# How to iterate through pandas columns and replace cells with information with the next row down

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to loop through a pandas dataframe column and based on if the next row down does not include "Property Address" add the information from that next row down to the previous row. For example, if I have a column that goes from top to bottom ["Property Address", "Alternate Address", "Property Address"] I would like to take the information from "Alternate Address" and add that information to the column above it ("Property Address"). I have already double checked that there are no trailing or leading spaces and that everything is lower case so that all comparisons will work. However, I still get this error:

```
if i == "Property Address" and df.loc[i+1, :] != "Property Address":

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Does anyone have ideas on what I can do so that this will work? I am new to Python, and I am really lost. Please let me know if there is any more information that I should provide to make answering this question easier. Thanks

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_excel('BRH.xls') # Reads the Excel File and creates a 
dataframe 
# Column Headers
df = df[['street', 'state', 'zip', 'Address Type', 'mStreet', 'mState', 'mZip']]

propertyAddress = "Property Address" # iterates thru column and replaces 
the current row with info from next row down

for i in df['Address Type']:
  if i == "Property Address" and df.loc[i+1, :] != "Property Address":
      df['mStreet'] == df.loc[i + 1, 'street']
      df['mState'] == df.loc[i + 1, 'state']
      df['mZip'] = df.loc[i + 1, 'zip']

df.to_excel('BRHOut.xls')
print('operation complete in:', time.process_time(), 'ms')
```

Comment: Can you show us an *example* of your input data [sensitive data excluded, we just need to know the format]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) to construct an appropriate mask.

Here's some untested pseudo-code:

```
m1 = df['AddressType'].shift() == 'Property Address'
m2 = df['AddressType'] != 'Property Address'
mask = m1 & m2

for col in ['Street', 'State', 'Zip']:
    df.loc[mask, 'm'+col] = df.loc[mask, col.lower()].shift(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TypeError` is happening because `i` is a string. When you call `df.loc[i+1, :]`, you are attempting to do something like `"Property Address" + 1`. Once you resolve that, you will still have some indexing issues in the body of your for loop.

@jpp gave a very succinct answer, but I believe that it pulls information from the intended destination and writes it to the intended source. In other words, the roles of "Property Address" and "Alternate Address" are reversed. I believe this will deliver the correct result:

### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'street': [
            '123 Main Street',
            '1600 Pennsylvania Ave',
            '567 Fake Ave',
            '1 University Ave'
        ],
        'state': ['CA', 'DC', 'DC', 'CA'],
        'zip': ['95126', '20500', '20500', '94301'],
        'Address Type': [
            'Property Address',
            'Alternate Address',
            'Property Address',
            'Alternate Address'
        ],
        'mStreet': [None, None, None, None],
        'mState': [None, None, None, None],
        'mZip': [None, None, None, None],
    },
    columns=[
        'street',
        'state',
        'zip',
        'Address Type',
        'mStreet',
        'mState',
        'mZip'
    ])

# Create a new dataframe with all address attributes shifted UP one row
next_address_attributes = df[['Address Type', 'street', 'state', 'zip']].shift(-1)

# Create a series to indicate whether information should be drawn from next row
# All the decision-making is right here
get_attributes_from_next_address = ((df['Address Type'] == 'Property Address')
    & (next_address_attributes['Address Type'] != 'Property Address'))
```

### Using For Loop

```
for i, getting_attributes_is_necessary in get_attributes_from_next_address.iteritems():
    if getting_attributes_is_necessary:
        df.at[i, 'mStreet'] = next_address_attributes.at[i, 'street']
        df.at[i, 'mState'] = next_address_attributes.at[i, 'state']
        df.at[i, 'mZip'] = next_address_attributes.at[i, 'zip']
```

### Loopless

```
df.loc[get_attributes_from_next_address, 'mStreet'] = next_address_attributes.loc[get_attributes_from_next_address, 'street']
df.loc[get_attributes_from_next_address, 'mState'] = next_address_attributes.loc[get_attributes_from_next_address, 'state']
df.loc[get_attributes_from_next_address, 'mZip'] = next_address_attributes.loc[get_attributes_from_next_address, 'zip']
```